# Who is the responsible setting a keyboard as default after resetting phone

Tags: android, android-source

when I build a custom android OS and after run on my phone, I have a custom keyboard want to run as default but nothing comes up with the click on input field finally I set as manually on `settings > keyboard manager > current keyboard`, I don't want to be set manually. So Which code is using to set a custom keyboard as default  and which application is handling the input managers

Comment: Thank you #Sulfkain